# Writing a domain with a Many2one field

Tags: xml, many-to-many, odoo-10

Ok, I'm working with multi company and on my form I have company_ids.  I'm trying to hide another field based on the values in company_ids.  Here is what i've tried.

```
attrs="{'invisible': [('company_ids', '!=', [(6, False, [3])])]}"
attrs="{'invisible': [('company_ids', '!=', 3)]}"
attrs="{'invisible': [('company_ids', 'not in', [3])]}"
attrs="{'invisible': [('company_ids', 'child_of', [(6, False, [4])])]}"
attrs="{'invisible': [('company_ids', 'child_of', [4])]}"
attrs="{'invisible': [('company_ids', 'not in', 3])]}"
attrs="{'invisible': [('company_ids', '!=', '3']}"
attrs="{'invisible': [('company_ids', '!=', 'Company Name')]}"
```

I can't figure out why I cannot get this to work.  All of the above just hide the field.

Comment: From your question it's not clear what you are trying to do with those domains. Please be accurate with your description and details to be able to help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a way around it.  I created a boolean field for each company, then cycled through company_ids and set it the booleans to true if the company id was in the list.  Then I used the following domain [('is_company_1', '=', False)].